# How can I use multiple operands in an if condition (ModX)

Tags: if-statement, modx, modx-revolution

I am using the if-extra for ModX. Is it possible to use mutliple operands, meaning write this code in a shorter way:

```
  [[!If?
       &subject=`[[!getUrlParam? &name=`id`]]`
       &operator=`EQ`
       &operand=`1`
       &then=`do something`
    ]]


[[!If?
   &subject=`[[!getUrlParam? &name=`id`]]`
   &operator=`EQ`
   &operand=`2`
   &then=`do something`
]]


[[!If?
   &subject=`[[!getUrlParam? &name=`id`]]`
   &operator=`EQ`
   &operand=`3`
   &then=`do something`
]]
```

Couldn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could work with this solution:

```
 [[If?
       &subject=`[[!getUrlParam? &name=`id`]]`
       &operator=`inarray`
       &operand=`1,2,3`
       &then=`do something`
    ]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try https://modx.com/extras/package/switch extra.

```
[[!switch? 
   &get=`[[!getUrlParam? &name=`id`]]` 
   &c1=`1`
   &do1=`do something1`
   &c2=`2`
   &do2=`do something2`
   &c3=`3`
   &do3=`do something3`
   &default=`default value`
]]
```