# How to hide a block from children of a resource in MODX Revo?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have a widget in sidebar that I want to show on all pages except the children of a container with id, for example, 418 (at the same time the widget should be visible for 418).
Didn't find anything similar in `IF` package.

Comment: Are you using getResources? If that's the case use `&parents="1,2,3,-418"` in the snippet call (where 1,2 and 3 represent other resource IDs).

Comment: I have ~800 resources, I think it's not my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and somewhat primitive solution could be just creating a new template by slightly modifying the current one (removing the widget) and then setting the newly created template for the pages where the widget shouldn't be shown.

The second approach I thought about is to get [somehow](https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/other-development-resources/class-reference/modx/modx.getparentids) a resource's parent id and then use it in a "proxy" chunk (instead of calling the widget's chunk directly) inside your current template like this:

```
[[!If?
&subject=`[[!getParentId]]`
&operator=`EQ`
&operand=`418`
&then=``
&else=`[[$yourWidget]]`
]]
```

There should be some extras with needed functionality to get parent's id or you can always write your own small "getParentId" snippet based on this:

```
return $modx->getParentIds( $modx->resource->id );
```

Comment: Parent ID could be got with `[[*parent]]`. I thought about this approach, but stuck on implementing multiple values to `&operand` key. Found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101931/how-can-i-use-multiple-operands-in-an-if-condition-modx

Comment: oooh...you are right, I just missed `[[*parent]]`. MODX is awesome!)